# Qt - Cannot open include file - subdir

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am new with Qt and Qt Creator. I have created some sub-directories in order to separate the classes of the project. Now, I am trying to include the headers in their respective sources but unsuccesfully.

I have separated the project as follow (-> means subdir):

```
Headers
   -> common
      -> tools
         abc.h

Sources
   -> common
      -> tools
         abc.cpp
```

in tools directories I have abc class. In my .pro file, it shows the following:

```
 HEADERS+= \
          Headers/common/tools/abc.h

 SOURCES += \
          Sources/common/tools/abc.cpp
```

Even though I cleaned and runned again qmake, there is a problem: when I want to include "abc.h" into "abc.cpp" in this way:

abc.cpp

```
 #include "Header/common/tools/abc.h"
```

Qt Creator shows this problem:

```
 C1083: Cannot open include file:  Headers/common/tools/abc.h: No such file or directory
```

I guess it is a problem of path which I can't find out. Can you? Thank you in advance

Comment: Where does .pro file located ? In other words: what is a full path to .pro file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
INCLUDEPATH += Header/common/tools
```

to .pro file and include your header simply like this

```
#include "abc.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the [INCLUDEPATH](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) variable to add the folder where "Header" is located. Every path in a `#include` directive will be prepended by path in include path when searching for headers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that the file was not in the right directory....so basic mistake! thank you all and sorry for bothering for that!

Answer (score 0):

**If I were you I would get a QT book**. There are many of these little idiosyncrazies, and a book makes sense of it all when you read it in sequence.

I read this [QT3 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131240722), and it was the best tech-book I ever read, but it is out of date now. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) is one by the same author - I got that one too, and it is good too. Haven't read all of it.